# Regex - Capture words within boundaries

Tags: regex, capture

I am new to Regex and am having difficulty capturing some data from a web scrape. The strings I have are in the form:

`\n\n\n\nHELLO & EVERYONE\n What's up?`

And I want to capture everything within the 4 `\n`s and the other `\n`.

i.e. `HELLO & EVERYONE`

I haven't been able to get anything to work, something along the lines of `/ \n{4}(\w+)\n /`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use: `(?:\\n){4}(.*)\\n`

You will need to wrap your "`\n`" in a non capturing group otherwise the system will treat it as "try and match `n` 4 times" instead.

Also `\` is a special character so you'll have to specify `\\` but note "not applicable to Javascript".

So what that expression means is that, look for \n\n\n\n and then capture everything from there until until you see the next `\n`

See:
https://regex101.com/r/yA9mV3/1

Also, incase you are doing Javascript, here is an implementation;

```js
var data = "\n\n\n\nHELLO & EVERYONE\n What's up"

var matches = /(?:\n){4}(.*)\n/.exec(data);

console.log(matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that `\n` does actually mean newlines.

```
/\n{4}(.+)\n/m
```

https://regex101.com/r/rG3sM4/2

You missed the `m` for Multiline matches.

And `\w` doesn't match spaces, so better use `.`.